# Why can't the Java compiler find my JARs?

Tags: java, junit, ant, javac, ivy

I made a GitHub repo to help explain my issue: https://github.com/matthiasdenu/jacoco-bug. But basically, I don't understand why `javac -cp lib/ test/*` doesn't work and fails with an error saying it can't find classes (that are in the JARs on the classpath I tried to specify)

```
denu:jacoco-bug denu$ javac -cp lib/ test/*
test/TestClass.java:2: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
                       ^
test/TestClass.java:2: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
^
test/TestSuite.java:1: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.ClassRule;
                ^
test/TestSuite.java:2: error: package org.junit.runners does not exist
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
                        ^
test/TestSuite.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
@RunWith(Suite.class)
 ^
  symbol: class RunWith
test/TestSuite.java:5: error: package Suite does not exist
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
      ^
test/TestClass.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
  @Test
   ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class TestClass
test/TestSuite.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
@RunWith(Suite.class)
         ^
  symbol: class Suite
8 errors
denu:jacoco-bug denu$
```

Comment: I don't see any JARs mentioned in your classpath, only a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
javac -cp lib/*;test/*
```

Why would this work?

- The `;` (or `:` on some operating systems) is the path-separator. You need this because `-cp` only accepts one argument (which can be multiple paths separated by the path separator).
- The `lib/*` should match all jars in the `lib` folder.
- The `test/*` should match all jars in the `test` folder.

Comment: 1) I don't thing the OP wants `test/*` to match JAR files.  I think that is supposed to match source files.  2) Using regular pathname expansion (globbing) won't generate a valid classpath.  You need to use the special classpath wildcard mechanism.

Comment: It works for me [in this .sh file](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/main/build/optaplanner-distribution-internal/src/main/assembly/scripts/runExamples.sh#L9), for Linux and Mac, and similarly in the .bat file for windows. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Ivy downloads the dependencies (JARs) to the `lib/` directory. My source files were in the `src/` and `test/` directories.

As mentioned in Geoffrey De Smet's answer, the classpath option takes one argument.

`$ java -cp lib/junit-4.13.2.jar src/* test/*` partially solves my problem.

To add all of the JARs in the `lib/` I would need to add every `*.jar` file to the classpath argument, separated by path separators.

Ant allows you to do this with a `fileset`.

```
    <target name="build" depends="ivy" description="--> compile and build this test project"> 
        <mkdir dir="out/classes" />

        <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        </path>

        <javac classpathref="classpath" destdir="out/classes" includeantruntime="false">
            <src path="src"/>
            <src path="test"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
```

GitHub commit: https://github.com/matthiasdenu/jacoco-bug/commit/a57fb5957bcc43c9c05a304a61b6ea956e1cca00

Comment: *"To add all of the JARs in the lib/ I would need to add every *.jar file to the classpath argument, separated by path separators."* - There is a better way.  Classpath wildcards.  See my answer.  But I agree that using a build tool such as Ant is even better ... though I would recommend Maven or Gradle as better tools.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `test/*` was intended to match only `*.java` files, what you need is one of the following:

```
javac -cp lib/something.jar test/*.java
```

This puts one JAR file on the classpath

```
javac -cp lib/something.jar;lib/another.jar test/*.java  # Windows
javac -cp lib/something.jar:lib/another.jar test/*.java  # linux or Mac
```

This puts two JAR files on the classpath.  Note that different classpath separators are used on Windows versus other platforms.

```
javac -cp 'lib/*.jar' test/*.java
```

This is using a classpath wildcard to match all of the JAR files in the `lib` directory.  Notice that I quoted `'lib/*.jar'` from attempting to do "globbing" on the argument.  The `*.jar` needs to be handled by `javac` itself.

For more information on setting the classpath, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

---

However, I strongly recommend that you don't do your builds by running `javac` from the command line or from clunky shell scripts or barch files.  Instead learn a Java build tool such as Maven, Gradle, Ant and so on.  Maven and Gradle understand how to retrieve your dependencies from a remote repository, and they will take care of assembling the classpaths for you.